# Django form and CBV CreateView not able to assign request.user to user field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a form and a CBV CreateView. I need to assign the request.user to the user field (Foreign Key to CustomUser model), which in the form is a hidden field (user). However, I have tried in the form **init** method by "self.fields['user'] = self.request.user.id" and I get the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'.  What is the most clean way of achieving this?

I have tried many different ways of doing it with no luck. ):

This is my form:

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Phone
    fields = 'user', 'phone_name', 'country', 'phone_number', 'phone_type', 'primary'
    widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()} 

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(PhoneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['user'] = self.request.user.id
        self.fields['primary'].help_text = _('<strong>Check:</strong> If this is your main contact phone number.')

  def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(PhoneForm, self).clean()

        user = cleaned_data.get('user')
        phone_name = cleaned_data.get('phone_name')
        country = cleaned_data.get('country')
        phone_number = cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        phone_type = cleaned_data.get('phone_type')
        primary = cleaned_data.get('primary')
        print('user: ',user)
        print('phone_name: ',phone_name)
        print('country: ',country)
        print('phone_number: ',phone_number)
        print('phoe_type: ',phone_type)
        print('primary: ',primary)

        if "action_add" in self.request.POST:
            try:
                phonenum = Phone.objects.filter(user=user, country=country, phone_number=phone_number).first()
                if phonenum:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('This Phone is registered already.'))
            except Phone.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            try:
                phone = Phone.objects.filter(user=user, primary=True).first()
                if phone and primary:

                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('There is another "Primary" Phone #already.'), code='invalid')

            except Phone.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        if "action_update" in self.request.POST:

          if "country" in self.changed_data or "phone_number" in self.changed_data:

            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You can´t update the Country nor the Phone number of the existing Phone.'))
          try:
              phone = Phone.objects.filter(user=user, primary=True).first()
              if phone and primary and self.request.session['Phone_object_id'] != phone.id: 

                  raise forms.ValidationError(_('There is another "Primary" Phone #already.'), code='invalid')

          except Phone.DoesNotExist:
              pass                  
        if not phone_name and not phone_type and not phone_number:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You have to fill out the form!'))
```

This is my view:

```
class PhoneCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PhoneForm
    model = Phone
    template_name = 'phones/addPhone.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('account_login')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('phonesList')

    class Meta:
        readonly = ('user', )

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kw = super(PhoneCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kw['request'] = self.request 
        return kw

    def get_initial(self):

        phone = Phone.create(self.request.user.id)
        form = self.form_class(instance=phone)
        form.instance.user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)

        return {'form': form, }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(PhoneCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        form = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
        form.instance.user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)      

        context = {
            'form': form,
            'user': self.request.user.id,
        }
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):

        form.instance.user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id) 

        form.instance.status = 'A' 
        form.instance.status_dt = timezone.now()
        form.instance.at_user = self.request.user.email
        form.instance.at_ip = visitor_ip_address(self.request) 
        form.instance.at_dttm = timezone.now()
        form.instance.at_action = 'Create Phone number'

        messages.success(self.request, _('Your Phone Number has been registered.'))
        return super(PhoneCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is my model:

```
class Phone(models.Model):

   PHONETYPES = (
       ('1', _('Mobile')),
       ('2', _('Home')),
       ('3', _('Work')),
       ('4', _('Other')),
   )
   status = models.CharField(_("Record Status"), max_length=1, default='A')
   status_dt = models.DateTimeField(_("Status Date"), default=timezone.now)
   user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   phone_name = models.CharField(_("Phone name"), max_length=20, default="PH"+str(random.randint(1,99999)))

   country = models.IntegerField(_("Country Dialing Code"))

   phone_number = models.CharField(_("Phone Number"), max_length=11)

   phone_type = models.CharField(_("Phone Type"), max_length=1, default="4", choices=PHONETYPES)

   verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=False)
   primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=False)

   at_user = models.CharField(_("Audit Trail (user)"), max_length=255, blank=True)
   at_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(_("Audit Trail (IP)"), protocol='both', blank=True, null=True)
   at_dttm = models.DateTimeField(_("Audit Trail (Date-Time)"), default=timezone.now)
   at_action = models.CharField(_("Audit Trail (Function performed)"), max_length=255, blank=True)
   UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'country', 'phone_number'], name='user_unique_phone_number')

   class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Phone Number")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Phone Numbers")

   @classmethod
   def create(cls, user):
       phone = cls(user= get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=user))
       # phone create
       return phone

   def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change a few things. First the hidden field user (which is foreign key to the user table) was taken out from the form and from the fields. Instead I used a session parameter where I stored the user id. Then I had to reformulate my method get_context_data in the view. The following is the updated code:

My new form:

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
  class Meta:
    model = Phone
    
    fields = 'phone_name', 'country', 'phone_number', 'phone_type', 'primary'
    #widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()} 

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        
        if self.request is None:
            self.request = kwargs['instance']
        
        super(PhoneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        
        self.fields['primary'].help_text = _('<strong>Check:</strong> If this is your main contact phone number.')
   

  def clean(self):
        
        cleaned_data = super(PhoneForm, self).clean()
        
        customUser = self.request.session['user_id']
        phone_name = cleaned_data.get('phone_name')
        country = cleaned_data.get('country')
        phone_number = cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        phone_type = cleaned_data.get('phone_type')
        primary = cleaned_data.get('primary')

        try:
            del self.request.session['validation_error']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        
        if "action_add" in self.request.POST:
            
            try:
                phonenum = Phone.objects.filter(customUser=customUser, country=country, phone_number=phone_number).first()
                if phonenum:
                    #messages.error(self.request, _('This Phone is registered already.')) 
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('This Phone is registered already.'))
            except Phone.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            
            try:
                phone = Phone.objects.filter(customUser=customUser, primary=True).first()
                if phone and primary:
                    
                    #messages.error(self.request, _('There is another "Primary" Phone already.'))
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('There is another "Primary" Phone #already.'), code='invalid')
                    
            except Phone.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            
        if "action_update" in self.request.POST:
          
          if "country" in self.changed_data or "phone_number" in self.changed_data:
                        
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You can´t update the Country nor the Phone number of the existing Phone.'))
          try:
              phone = Phone.objects.filter(customUser=customUser, primary=True).first()
              if phone and primary and self.request.session['Phone_object_id'] != phone.id: 
                  
                  raise forms.ValidationError(_('There is another "Primary" Phone #already.'), code='invalid')
                  
          except Phone.DoesNotExist:
              pass                  
        if not phone_name and not phone_type and not phone_number:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You have to fill out the form!'))
  
        return cleaned_data
```

and my new get_context_data method in the view is:

```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #Use this to add extra context.#
        context = super(PhoneCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
        form.instance.customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        self.request.session['user_id'] = self.request.user.id

        return context
```