# request.user returns AnonymousUser even when user is logged in

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I would like to create a user when saving an object to the database but every time it says the user is AnonymousUser even though the user is logged in, below is a snippet, any help would be appreciated.

```
 def post(self, request):
    response = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8')) 

    result_code = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]

    if result_code == 0:
        if response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][2]["Name"] == 'Balance':
            del response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][2]

        amount = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][0]["Value"]
        mpesa_receipt_number = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][1]["Value"]
        transaction_date = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][2]["Value"]
        phone_number = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][3]["Value"]

        str_transaction_date = str(transaction_date)
        transaction_datetime = datetime.strptime(
            str_transaction_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        aware_transaction_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(
            transaction_datetime)

        our_model = Mpesa.objects.create(
            Paid_user=request.user
            MpesaReceiptNumber=mpesa_receipt_number,
            PhoneNumber=phone_number,
            Amount=amount,
            TransactionDate=aware_transaction_datetime,
        )

        our_model.save()
```

Comment: are using a custom user model?

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom user model.

Comment: self.request.user Check this guys answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541631/15220219

Comment: see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376985/django-request-user-is-always-anonymous-user

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `permission_classes`  in your view like this -

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class SomeView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # now here in your post you will be able to use `request.user` to know the user requesting this view.
        pass
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Still getting this error `ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000001E235C2D6A0>>": "Mpesa.Paid_user" must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: are you using a class base view or function based view.

Comment: it's a class-based view

Comment: can you please post your `User` model

Comment: `Paid_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`